# Copy-Paste data from two cells within the sheet if another cell value is true on the same sheet;but the data to be pasted within a specific range

Tags: vba, excel

I require to paste the value of 2 cells to a different destination on the same sheet, having checked the condition to be true.

Columns K and L have the data that needs to be copied if condition is true on column M. Total range of data would be from K8 to K18; similarly for L and M.

If Value of column M is "Y" then values of K and L on the same row needs to be pasted to the same sheet in column D and E, but it should start with row 12 and paste any other value if "Y" below each other without blanks.

The loop should stop checking at row 18 and the data cannot be pasted beyond row 22.

[image: screen-shot from excel]

Kindly check the screen shot.
 if any other information is required; kindly let me know.

```
 Sub Search_and_Move()

Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim FoundX As Range, Firstfound As String, Lastrow As Long

Set wsSource = Worksheets("Draft")     ' Source worksheet
Set wsDest = Worksheets("Draft")       ' Destination worksheet

' Find the first cell in column M with an "Y" in it
Set FoundX = wsSource.Range("M:M").Find("Y", After:=wsSource.Range("M" & Rows.Count), _
                             LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

If FoundX Is Nothing Then

    MsgBox "No Y's found.", vbCritical, "Done!"
    Exit Sub

Else    'Copy values


    Firstfound = FoundX.Address                                     ' Remember the first found "Y" cell address. Prevents an endless loop.

    Lastrow = wsSource.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1      ' Next empty row on Destination sheet
    If Lastrow < 11 Then Lastrow = 11

    Do

        'Copy K:L values from source worksheet to next empty row on the destination worksheet in columns D:E
        wsDest.Range("D" & Lastrow).Resize(1, 2).Value = FoundX.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 2).Value

        Lastrow = Lastrow + 1                                       ' Row counter

        Set FoundX = wsSource.Range("M:M").FindNext(FoundX)         ' Find next "Y" in column M

    Loop Until FoundX.Address = Firstfound                          ' Do until the first "Y" address is found again

End If

MsgBox "All Y values copied.", vbInformation, "Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: code added to the thread. This code makes it to copy the header of the columns. and while pasting it will check for the last entry in the row. I need the macro to always to start pasting data at on row 12 every time.

The code has been copied and edited a bit.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are doing this by means of a Macro? This would be easily managed by a simple `INDEX(MATCH())` formula... In terms of your loop though, is the data always going to be fixed for rows 8 to 18? I would perhaps just loop through the 11 cells in the M column if that's the case as with such a small data set there wouldn't be any performance issues

Comment: the file crashes when i use the index match formula, Ive used the formula to bring to the interface sheet this data.

Comment: Yes the range will be always fixed through the columns, but the data within the cells can be changed.

Comment: @user2502611
Hi, can anyone edit the formula, so that always the paste would start with row 12 and end at row 22

Comment: @Chris Can I ask what is not working with your code? I just ran your code through a dummy sheet and it pulled the 6 "Y" values into the range "D12:E17". Please could you let me know what issues you are facing?